# How to set the style for Android Search Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, search

I am using a [Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#TheBasics) and I want to set the style so as to decide the tint of the arrow, the magnifying glass, and the underline. Also I want to style the "suggestionsView". Right now my xml only has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MySuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >
</searchable>
```

When I try to force certain common attributes such as `android:background="@color/primary"` the searchable ignores the attributes.

So is there a way to access the constituent Views and style them programmatically? I want to style both the EditText and the item view of the adapter that provides the suggestions

Comment: What arrow? I didn't see one.

Comment: There is a grayish arrow next to the icon. When you click on it, the view disappears.

Comment: All the attributes related to the searchView are listed in my answer.

Comment: btw my app does not have an actionBar. My theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`